# Enable result cache for uncontrolable queries in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

I was learning how to implement Redis cache for queries with doctrine2 and symfony 2 with this [link](http://olegpuzanov.com/2015/02/01/using-redis-for-doctrine-caching-in-symfony2/), it went all ok but my biggest problem are queries that i cannot control, that are run by the Entity in Symfony like this example:

```
SELECT s0_.id AS id_0, s0_.name AS name_1, ST_AsText(s0_.wkt)  AS 
wkt_2, s0_.strategy AS strategy_3, s0_.type AS type_4, s0_.deleted_at 
AS deleted_at_5, s0_.beach_id AS beach_id_6, s0_.pmp_id AS pmp_id_7 
FROM stretch s0_ 
WHERE (s0_.pmp_id = ?) AND (s0_.deleted_at IS NULL) 
ORDER BY s0_.name ASC
```

I imagine that this is created by a default `findBy()` call from doctrine but I cant find how to set the `$query->useResultCache(true)` in this query.

Any way to set cache to these specific queries?

Comment: Is [Second Level Cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html#the-second-level-cache) what you mean?